# Is Refresh Token Rotation Support?

Tags: actions-on-google

So I have an action that has account linking configured using auth code flow. The refresh tokens are valid for a few years and do expire. As there are existing people linked to the actions I would like to avoid having them relink to get a new refresh token.

The IDp supports a refresh token rotation. If I were to implement this would this be supported by the actions on google platform? Would the new refresh token be stored?

https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/concepts/refresh-token-rotation

As FYI having an a refresh token which without expiry is not an option in this case due to security policy requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism to rotate a refresh token. If a refresh token expires and a new access token cannot be retrieved, the user will need to reauthenticate their account. You can read the [entirety of the OAuth guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/oauth-concept-guide) for more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

By docs yes:

> Note: You can optionally return a new refresh_token in your response. For more information about when returning a new refresh_token is preferred, see Working with tokens.

See: [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/oauth2?oauth=code#flow)

Comment: Tested now. If you have a one-time refresh token, Google is able to renew it (exchange to the new one during the refresh process).